# Looping through the xml Elements issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a large XMLTEXTREADER reads that I am getting.

Here is my code

```
while (reads.Read())
{
    switch (reads.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Element:
        {

            if (reads.Name == "TITLE")
            {
                Response.Write("<Br />");
                Intel = reads.ReadInnerXml();
            }
            Response.Write(Intel);
            Intel = "";

         }
         break;
     }
 }
```

This works Great for Printing the all  Tags in the Document. Now I Have a tag called Authors and for some Books there are more than one Author.

So MY XML LOOKS LIKE BELOW

```
<set1>
<title>Test </Title>
<intel_auth id="9">
<fname>ABC</fname>
 <mname>M.</mname>
<lname>app</lname>
  </intel_auth>
  <intel_auth id="130">
 <fname>Brad</fname>
 <lname>e</lname>
 </intel_auth_auth>
 <intel_auth id="31">
 <fname>Robin</fname>
 <lname>neil</lname>
 </intel_auth>
 <intel_auth id="232">
 <fname>Mason</fname>
 <lname>Rodriguez</lname>
</intel_auth>
</set1>
```

I have Multiple sets and it prints all the titles and not printing author names next to it.

I used below code

```
case XmlNodeType.Element:
                            {
                                //string strURI = reads.NamespaceURI;
                                //string name = reads.Name;
                                string Authors = "";

                                if (reads.Name == "TITLE")
                                {
                                    Response.Write("<Br />");

                                   Intel = reads.ReadInnerXml();

                                   if (reads.Name == "FNAME")
                                   {
                                       Authors += reads.Value;


                                   }
                                   if (reads.Name == "MNAME")
                                   {
                                       Authors += reads.Value;


                                   }
                                   if (reads.Name == "LNAME")
                                   {
                                       Authors += reads.Value;


                                   }

                                }

                                Response.Write(Intel+Authors);
                                Intel = "";
                                Authors = "";
                            }
                            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

When [ReadInnerXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readinnerxml.aspx) is called, it advances the reader to the next node after the close tag, therefore your code never sees the author name nodes. The documentation for the method gives the details.

Try [ReadStartElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7e4769a.aspx) to position it on the intel_auth element.

Answer (score 0):

Xml is case sensitive.  Change all your comparisons to match the case of your xml.  Title in your xml is both `title` and `Title` which is it?

If you don't mind, I can help you using Linq:

I'd create a class called Author (I'm using these extensions: http://searisen.com/xmllib/extensions.wiki)

```
public class Author
{
    XElement self;
    public Author(XElement self) { this.self = self; }

    public int Id { get { return self.Get("id", 0); } }
    public string LastName { get { return self.Get("lname", string.Empty); } }
    public string FirstName { get { return self.Get("fname", string.Empty); } }
    public string MiddleName { get { return self.Get("mname", string.Empty); } }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FirstName + MiddleName + LastName;
    }
}
```

Then a Book class:

```
public class Book
{
    XElement self;
    public Book(XElement self) { this.self = self; }

    public Author[] Authors
    {
        get { return _Authors ?? // if _Authors is null, create it and then return it
            (_Authors = self.GetEnumerable("intel_auth", xauthor => new Author(xauthor)).ToArray()); }
    }
    Author[] _Authors;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return self.Get("title", string.Empty); }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to load your books from your xml snippet, but if every book is a `set1` and `set1` are nodes of the root node of the file...

```
Book[] books = XElement.Load("file.xml")
                   .GetEnumerable("set1", xbook => new Book(xbook))
                   .ToArray();
```

Then you can loop over all the books, and all the authors in a book like:

```
foreach(Book book in books)
{
    Response.Write(book.Title); 
    foreach(Author author in book.Authors)
    {
        Response.Write("<Br />" + author.ToString());
    }
}
```